# Promise or Future in ruby-concurrency? When should be used which?

Tags: ruby, concurrency, promise, rubygems, future

In general promises and features are closely related, if not synonims. In the documentation of the gem https://github.com/ruby-concurrency it says so so too. Therefore, it's confusing which one should be used in what circumstances. And how are they related in the gem? Is one of a more low level or outdated than the other? Do they basically both do the same thing?

Also, existense of these make it even more confusing:

```
* Concurrent::Promises.future
* Concurrent::Promises::Future
* Concurrent::Future
* [...possibly something similar...]
```

Comment: The readme says that Futures are deprecated and replaced by Promises...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, `Future` is about asynchronous execution. It's a high level abstraction over system threads (Ruby `Thread` class). So when you need to speed up and parallelize some calculations then you need to use threads. But it's some kind of low level things so it's easier to use `Future`s instead. The one of the benefits is that usually implementations of `Future`s use thread pool so you can manage the level of concurrency and system resource consuming. So the problem which `Future` solves is complexity of low-level threads concurrency model.

On the other hand `Promise` is about architecture and composition. Not about concurrency. It's a high level abstraction over callbacks and is a subtype of `Observer` pattern. It allows to decouple component which produces some result
and component which consumes this result. Both producer and consumer may know nothing about each other. So the problem which `Promise` solves is complexity and coupling that you get with callbacks approach.

So, regarding `concurrent-ruby`. They provide both classic versions of `Promise` and `Future`. But now they also provide a new API - `Promises` (with `s` at the end) which looks like just a combination of promises and futures with uniformed API. It implements (actually reuses) `Promise` and `Future` libraries but provides some new interface over them. For instance future behaves similar to promise and allows to register callbacks and can be chained similar to promises.

Comment: why is promise not about concurrency if promise and future are basically synonims?

Comment: Promises could be used in completely synchronous code. It's a way to organize callbacks.